# Neural networks - skipping some sequence elements, when the class label cannot be determined?

Tags: neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to use LSTM neural networks to make some binary predictions on biological sequences. But there are some elements of the sequences that for some reason cannot be assigned to any of my class labels. My first thought was to simply skip the elements, but it doesn't seem to be a good approach to apply when using a method designed to capture long-term dependencies. Have you ever had a similar problem?

To be more specific:

> DEAQFKECYDTCHKECSDKGNGFTFCEMKCDTDCSVKDVKEKLENYKPKN

is an example sequence

> 00000000000000000000000000000000XXX111111111111111

are class labels for the sequence. X means, that the real class label cannot be determined. It can appear everywhere in the sequence, not only between two regions with distinct labels, as in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing I've found a solution: masking
https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking